# How can I always keep encrypted data bags "encrypted"?

Tags: encryption, chef-infra, chef-recipe, databags

In one of my chef recipes, I am using encrypted data bags to do hide the download path for a remote file resource that I have defined. 
However when converging on a node, if the download fails for whatever reason, then I can see all my secrets in the log.

Since I'm planning to deploy this on a CI server, I really don't want to have it displayed.

Is there any way to keep the data encrypted even on error?

Comment: Question doesn't make a lot of sense. You're trying to hide the download URL in a databag and you don't want this URL to appear in the log when it fails?... Begs the question how does one troubleshoot a failed download if one can't see the URL?  To minimize information leakage I suggest you ensure the logs are only readable by root and set logging to ERROR or WARN levels.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `sensitive` attribute on the resource.  This suppresses a lot of log data for some resources. For example, `template` resources will not log their contents when the `sensitive` attribute is set to `true`.  I doubt it will suppress the URL of a `remote_file`, but it's worth a shot.